# Automatically refresh/compile in IntelliJ in a "nightly dev machine update"

Tags: intellij-idea, automation, ui-automation, intellij-plugin, remote-control

We are using a small tool to automatically fetch updates for various projects from Git/SVN, recompile them and run tests locally with any local modifications that the developer might have developed, but not yet submitted to the global code repositories.

For some large projects, we see that the IntelliJ IDE only does refreshing/recompiling of code when the developer comes in and actually starts to work in the IDE, which always causes some time in the morning when the machines are busy recompiling, thus hindering the developers shortly after they came in.

I would like to do such a refresh/recompile already during the nightly update, so it is not wasting dev-time in the morning.

For Eclipse we are using https://github.com/moschinski/MondShell, a plugin which provides remote control functionality.

I tried to look for tools to automate things in IntelliJ, but could not find anything that would suit.

Are there any plugins or other means of remotely controlling IntelliJ to force it to recompile code and update source repositories?

Answer (score 0):

As I could not find anything which could do this I started a small plugin which provides a small REST interface in order to control things in IntelliJ from scripts.

See https://github.com/centic9/IntelliJ-Automation-Plugin for the implementation details.